# Set vertical position of HTML element

Tags: javascript, html

If I take out the variable counter and just set `document.getElementById("movee").style.top` equal to a number, it works fine. Combining the variable counter and that bit of code would theoretically get an image to move. It's not working for some reason though!

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
    #movee
    {
        position:absolute;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function goDown()
    {
        var counter=1; 
        while (counter<300)
        {
            document.getElementById("movee").style.top="counter";
            var counter=counter+1;
        }
    }
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="goDown()" value="Move!">
<img src="test.png" id="movee"></img>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're setting the top style property of #movee to the string "counter" not the value of the variable counter

```
document.getElementById("movee").style.top=counter+"px";
```

Also it seems you are trying to animate the element, your technique will not work as the update will occur only after your script finish running. I suggest looking into css transitions, or a library that does animations like jQuery(jQuery.animate).

Comment: Not 100% sure on this, but would using setTimeout and a curried function (for variable scoping) allow the movement to take place while the function runs?  Also, +1 for suggesting places where others have solved this problem already (jquery or css transitions, specifically transition:translate()).

Comment: setTimeout could work but I foresee it causing the op a lot more problems.

Comment: True that.  OP should use jquery or css if possible and stop trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thank you, and yeah, I'll just use jQuery instead.

Answer (score 0):

remove the quotes from "counter" and after that line do not use "var counter", just counter +=1

Answer (score 0):

Even if your code to set the top style was correct, your element wouldn't animate because the code doesn't return control to the browser during the loop. Instead it would appear to move all 300 pixels at once.